# How do double quotes and angle bracket work in this scenario?

Tags: xss

Question about a solution in portswigger academy (since portswigger explains nothing and I can't find any info elsewhere on this):

Break out of the img attribute by searching for:

[image: ">]

Here is the img attribute being broken out of:

[image]

How do the double quote and angle bracket break out of the attribute exactly?  I can't figure out how the double quotes play a role in that.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given the example, the rendered search result is effectively this:

`<img src="...tracker.gif?searchterm="<svg onload=alert(1)>">`

The leading quote of the crafted search term serves to terminate the `src` attribute from the `img` tag. This leaves the `svg` entity whole, and ready to be parsed and executed as syntacticly correct JavaScript at page load time, inline to the HTML tag.

The final rendered HTML has a hanging double quote which is invalid HTML, but I'm guessing the parser basically ignores it when it gets to the closing angle bracket for the `img` tag, then renders the rest of the page normally.

So if that alert pops up, then you have a XSS vulnerability in that example. You could paste that result into an HTML page, open with a browser, to confirm.

Without the leading quote, the crafted search term would just be a delimited string, and wouldn't execute in the on page load JS context.

Comment: 'The leading quote of the crafted search term serves to terminate the src attribute from the img tag.' How? It would be seachTerms=">.  How does this terminate the src attribute?  Wouldn't this then make it  seachTerms=">"><svg.....  ?  thanks

Comment: Just type out the string replacing abc123 with the injected search term. It is as I show above I believe.

Comment: Made a further edit to the rendered html that should make it more clear.